# Bijection, arrow position

Tags: positioning

How can I adjust the following arrows such that the arrow heads of `longmapsto` and `longmapsfrom` are in accordance with those ones of `longleftrightarrow`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    A &\longleftrightarrow B\\
    a &\longmapsto b \\
    a &\longmapsfrom b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I just want to place `\longmapsto` a little bit more to the right. The third arrow is in accordance with the first one, but the second arrow is not. I would like to try out a solution without changed arrow lengths. I just want the output almost as in my example, with the only difference that the second arrow should be positioned a little bit more to the right such that the arrow head is exactly below the arrow head above.

Alternatively, I can define

```
\begin{align*}
A \longleftrightarrow{}& B\\
a \longmapsto{}& b \\
a \longmapsfrom{}& b
\end{align*}
```

but then I get the roles interchanged. The second arrow is now in accordance with the first one, but the third is not.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean the length of the stems? The arrow heads are the same.

Comment: I mean that the arrow heads should be exactly one above the other. That means, `longmapsto` should be positioned such that its arrow head should be in the same horizontal position as the right arrow head of `longleftrightarrow`, and analogously for the other arrow.

Answer (score 2):

The arrow heads are the same; the stems have different length, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\let\longleftrightarrow\relax % undefine the command to avoid a warning
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longleftrightarrow}{\leftarrow\bigjoinrel\rightarrow}
\newcommand\bigjoinrel{\mathrel{\mkern-7mu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A &\longleftrightarrow B\\
  a &\longmapsto b \\
  a &\longmapsfrom b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more refined definition, so that the difference in length is negligible also in subscripts/superscripts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\let\longleftrightarrow\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longleftrightarrow}{\leftarrow\bigjoinrel\rightarrow}
\newcommand\bigjoinrel{\mathrel{\mkern-6.78mu\nonscript\mkern-0.22mu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A &\longleftrightarrow B\\
  a &\longmapsto b \\
  a &\longmapsfrom b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use some padding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\bijpad}{\mathrel{\mkern4mu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A &\longleftrightarrow B\\
  a &\longmapsto\bijpad b \\
  a &\bijpad\longmapsfrom b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way without shortening the stem?

Comment: @Thrash By lengthening the stems in `\longmapsto`.

Comment: And without lengthening? I just want to place `\longmapsto` a little bit more to the right, nothing more.

Comment: @Thrash I'm not seeing sense in that.

Comment: In my example, the third arrow is in accordance with the first one, but the second arrow is not.

Comment: @Thrash With different lengths, also the variables are not aligned with each other. For instance `b` in the second line is more left than `B` in the first line.

Comment: @Thrash Is the final version what you like? I wouldn't like it, personally.

Comment: I would like to test a solution (how it will look like). But if there isn't any, I'll probably use your first suggestion. See my very first post for updates. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple  way to align the right-hand side arrowheads. However I propose another solution, to centre `\longmapsto/from` w.r.t. `\longleftrightarrow`, which looks nicer, from my point of view:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage{makebox}

 \newcommand{\centredlmapsto}{ \mathrel{\makebox*{$\longleftrightarrow$}{$\longmapsto$}}}
\newcommand{\centredlmapsfrom}{ \mathrel{\makebox*{$\longleftrightarrow$}{$\longmapsfrom$}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  A & \longleftrightarrow B & \qquad A & \longleftrightarrow B \\
  a & \:\longmapsto b & a & \centredlmapsto b \\
  a & \longmapsfrom\: b & a & \centredlmapsfrom b
\end{alignat*}

\end{document} [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Okay, but in the left part the `b`s are not well adjusted. But one can use  `\begin{alignat*}{2}
 A &\longleftrightarrow{}&& B\\
 a &\:\longmapsto&& b \\
 a &\longmapsfrom&& b
 \end{alignat*}`

Comment: @Thrash: Right. I didn't even think of checking this alignment, as I focused on the arrows alignments. It's enough to add a `\:` before the `b` in the last row. Pleasesee the modified code and result.

Comment: Thanks! So the most easiest way (for non-centering) would be `\begin{align}
 A & \longleftrightarrow B  \\
 a & \:\longmapsto b  \\
 a & \longmapsfrom\: b
 \end{align}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @egreg I've found a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\bijpad}{\mathrel{\mkern4mu}} % probably not necessary

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    A &\longleftrightarrow{}&& B\\
    a &\bijpad\longmapsto&& b \\
  % a &\:\longmapsto&& b \\ % alternatively
    a &\longmapsfrom&& b
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

It seems that `\newcommand{\bijpad}{\mathrel{\mkern4mu}}` is not necessary. Instead one can simply add `\:` before `\longmapsto`.

**Probably the easiest way:**

```
\begin{align*}
A & \longleftrightarrow B  \\
a & \:\longmapsto b  \\
a & \longmapsfrom\: b
\end{align*}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of repeating the same solution I gave?

Comment: That's not your solution, but based on yours, a modification. You didn't use `alignat`. I had to use it so that the terms/variables beside the arrows are well positioned above each other.